# Changing CloudMade predefined icons

Tags: customization, cloudmade

I recently tried the Style Editor of CloudMade (http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor).
While I know how to change the color/ line style/ border of roads/ railways, but I couldn't find a way how to change the icons of specific building like hospitals/ schools/ places of worship.

Basically, I'd like to know how Life is Magic/Life is Crime, as mentioned in their case studies (http://cloudmade.com/case-studies), can change those places with their custom icons. Could it be they actually proccess them from raw data?

Thank You In Advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it by yourself as it is not free of charge. For more information, please write to support@cloudmade.com.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think it answers the question. If the answer is that you can't then that's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Red Robot Labs (RRL), the developer of Life is Magic and Life is Crime were able to change icons of specific buildings because they contracted CloudMade's cartographers to develop a custom style for them.

Some changes to the map style - like icons - require human oversight and guidance and are not supported by CloudMade's Style Editor tool.  The cartography services that CloudMade offers are available to any developer - get in touch with their support team for more details.

RRL did not custom render the maps themselves.